# Laravel make a dynamic dropdown using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.6 and my `User` table have a foreign key of `f_code` for `Faculty` and i have 2 dropdown select `Faculty` and `Programme`. The faculty dropdown would be automatically selected based on the login by using `Auth::user()->f-code` while the programme dropdown would only display programme based on the faculty (I have already done the relationship between the 2 table). I am trying to use ajax to return the `p_code` and `p_name` and append them in my `Programme` dropdown select but it isn't displaying any programme in the dropdown select. Anyone able to help me? Sorry if my question is slightly confusing i'm not sure how do i explain in words properly hope my codes can explain better.

Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

**Blade View**

```
<!-- FACULTY -->
<select id="Faculty" class="form-control Faculty">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Faculty</option>
    @foreach($FacultyList as $fac)
        <option value="{{$fac->f_code}}">{{$fac->f_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<br>
<!-- PROGRAMME -->
<select id="Programme" class="form-control Programme">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Programme</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var lecturer_faculty = '{{ Auth::user()->f_code }}'
    var facSelect = document.getElementById("Faculty");
    facSelect.value = lecturer_faculty;

    var div=$(this).parent();
    var op=" ";


    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('findProgramme')!!}',
        data:{'id':facSelect.value},
        success:function(data){
            op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Select Programme</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                op+='<option value="'+data[i].p_code+'">'+data[i].programme_name+'</option>';
            }
            div.find('.Programme').html(" "); 
            div.find('.Programme').append(op); 

        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
function index()
{

    $FacultyList = Faculty::all();
    return View::make('generateqr',compact('FacultyList')); 
}


function findProgramme(Request $request)
{
    $data = Programme::select('p_code','programme_name')->where('faculty_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

instead of dynamically using ajax i select the `Programme` data inside my controller and pass it into the view and use a loop to display all the programmes

**Blade View**

```
<!-- FACULTY -->
<select id="Faculty" class="form-control Faculty">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Faculty</option>
    @foreach($FacultyList as $fac)
        <option value="{{$fac->f_code}}">{{$fac->f_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<br>
<!-- PROGRAMME -->
<select id="Programme" class="form-control Programme">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Select Programme</option>
    @foreach($ProgrammeList as $prog)
        <option value="{{$prog->p_code}}">{{$prog->programme_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var lecturer_faculty = '{{ Auth::user()->f_code }}'
    var facSelect = document.getElementById("Faculty");
    facSelect.value = lecturer_faculty;
    facSelect.disabled = true;
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
function index()
{

    $FacultyList = Faculty::all();
    $ProgrammeList = Programme::select('p_code','programme_name')->where('faculty_id',Auth::user()->f_code)->take(100)->get();
    return View::make('generateqr',compact('FacultyList','ProgrammeList')); 
}


function findProgramme(Request $request)
{
    $data = Programme::select('p_code','programme_name')->where('faculty_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```